# How to plot and simulate reaction networks in Mathematica?

Tags: physics, chemistry

I am trying to simulate reaction networks like it's done in the Simulation methods
in this [paper](https://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000675). They used [Xcellerator](http://www.cellerator.org/), so I after installing on Mathmatica 11.2 and trying to run their [Belousov-Zhabotinski Reaction](http://www.cellerator.org/examples/index.html) example I got errors on obsolete functions.

What is the modern way to simulate their dynamic model, for example the one depicted here:

[image]

---

For example in their case they wrote down these equations:

> Hence, we can write 4 equilibrium relations involving the macroscopic
>   CaM states and 8 relations involving the microscopic CaM states (see
>   below). This yields 12 equations relating the 4 microscopic
>   equilibrium constants to the 4 macroscopic equilibrium constants.
>   There are 12 unknown concentrations of CaM states we would like to
>   eliminate. Eight variables can be eliminated among the 12 equations.
>   Conservation of atoms between the microscopic and macroscopic states
>   (3 equations) plus conservation of mass (one equation) provide the
>   necessary constraints to do so. Explicitly, for given constant [Ca2+]
>   and [CaM] one may solve the following equations for the equilibrium
>   dissociation constants:

$$
[CaM0][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^1 [CaM1] \\
[CaM1][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^2 [CaM2] \\
[CaM2][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^3 [CaM3] \\
[CaM3][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^4 [CaM4] \\
$$

$$
[CaM0][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^1C [CaM1C] \\
[CaM0][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^1N [CaM1N] \\
[CaM1C][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^2C [CaM2C] \\
[CaM2C][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^1N [CaM1N2C] \\
[CaM1N2C][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^2N [CaM2N2C] \\
[CaM2N1C][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^2C [CaM2N2C] \\
[CaM2N][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^1C [CaM2N1C] \\
[CaM1N1C][Ca^(2+)]=K_D^2N [CaM2N1C] \\
[CaM1N0C]+[CaM0N1C]=[CaM1] \\
[CaM1N1C]+[CaM0N2C]+[CaM2N0C]=[CaM2] \\
[CaM1N2C]+[CaM2N1C]=[CaM3] \\
$$
$$
∑_{(n=0)}^4[CaMn]=[CaM_TOTAL] 
$$

Comment: Is there a question? If so, it will require the actual Mathematica code, in copy-pastable form, if some sort of diagnosis is being requested.

Comment: related: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0146732

https://reaction-networks.net/wiki/Mathematics_of_Reaction_Networks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Xcellerator package, but I installed it on v12.0 and tried the BZ demo.  I also got the warnings `General::obspkg -- PlotLegends is now obsolete` and `Arrays:shdw -- Symbol Arrays appears in multiple contexts {Global, System}`, but the rest appears to basically work.

Comment: Since the authors of the paper you’re interested in used Mathematica and xcellerator, you could email them and ask for their code.